# List view project android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I need to do one agenda about some events. I have one list view with all titles about the events for this I use json and mysql for this .

The problem is I am new on android , and I dont know how to do when I click one event title have on Activity  with information about this event.

I have the information on database . Can you help me?  I need this  doing automatically .

My code now is this :

```
package com.eu.agendamarinhagrande;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.eu.agendamarinhagrande.JSONParser;
import com.eu.agendamarinhagrande.R;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.text.Normalizer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    // JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> empresaList;


    // url to get all products list
    private static String url_all_empresas = "http://www.grifin.pt/projectoamg/Conexao.php";

    // JSON Node names


    private static final String TAG_TITULO = "Titulo";


    // products JSONArray
    String resultado = null;

    ListView lista;

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Hashmap para el ListView
        empresaList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        new Download().execute();
        // Cargar los productos en el Background Thread

        lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        // ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        // actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }//fin onCreate


    public class Download extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String out = null;

            try {
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                final HttpParams httpParameters = httpClient.getParams();

                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 15000);
                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 15000);

                HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet(url_all_empresas);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

                out = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity, HTTP.UTF_8);

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return out;
        }


        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsa = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String str = jsa.getString("Titulo");
                    String data = jsa.getString("Datainicio");
                    Log.e("TAG", str);
                    Log.e("TAG", data);


                    String s1 = Normalizer.normalize(str, Normalizer.Form.NFKD);
                    String regex = Pattern.quote("[\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}\\p{IsLm}\\p{IsSk}]+");

                    str = new String(s1.replaceAll(regex, "").getBytes("ascii"), "ascii");

                    list.add(str+"\n"+data);

                }

                ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

                // updating listview
                //setListAdapter(adapter);
                lista.setAdapter(adapter);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Some information for you understand my code is portuguese so I translate for you

```
Titulo-- Title
Data---Date 
Descricao---Information about event
Id_evento---Id_event
Imagem---image
```

Comment: In that case, please just translate the source code, instead of having us do that for you. If you want an answer, please ask your question completely in English, since there are not as many people on this site who speak Portuguese.

Comment: Try to handle ListView onItemClickListener and pass event data to other activity using Intent extra.

Comment: Guy the problem isnt the code is the database mysql and about it cant do nothing

Answer (score 2):

You have to add an onItemClickListener to you listview.
mylistview.setOnItemClickListener(this);

where this is your activity`s instance. Make sure please, you activity is implementing the onItemClickListener interface.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements onItemClickListener{

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

   listView=  ((ListView) findViewById (R.id.list));
    listView.setOnItemClickListener (this);
 empresaList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    new Download().execute();
//download data to empresaList arrayList , and on PostExeCutre
// create a new adapter with it
// set it to list
  }

  public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
  {
//do what you want in your code.
  }
}
```

A long, but good example about onClickListeners:
http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/

Comment: at onItemClick you can grab you item:
list.get(position).getTitle(); where list is your List<String> with titles what you give to your adapter.

Comment: Guy i go try if i have some problem can you help me? i am really noob one android :c thanks^^

Comment: First, welcome in Android, second sure I can help. If my answer going to help it alone, please accept it. If we need more things to discuss I`ll add them later to my answer, so you can accept then.

Comment: Without problems i will accept only need check it first

Comment: I dont understand sorry, i add this code where one my main activity or one  new activity where i receive information about event?

Comment: When a user click on a listItem, the onClickEvent method get`s fire, if you registred you activity as a listener for listview onClick event. I had edit the answer, open the link please.

Comment: //do what you want in your code. give me one exemple i want on my new activity "Descricao" about this event  "Descricao" is one variable on json

Comment: ? can you please help me ?

Comment: Sorry, not now, I have a work to do. maybe late afternoon. Sorry about that. but check my edited answer